# PHP Mysql iis VPS - connect from remote server

Tags: php, mysql, iis

I have:
A shared hosting account with host X,
A VPS on host Y,
AND XAMPP to my home pc.

I have IIS on my vps and installed mysql and phpmyadmin (they work great). I want to be able to access my database on my VPS FROM my Shared hosting account.
 I use this script on my local PC using XAMMP and **i connect successfully to my REMOTE VPS database**.

```
$db_host = 'mydomain.com';
$db_user = 'admin';
$db_password = 'db_pass';
$db_name = 'db_name';
$db_port = '3306';

$mysqli = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name, $db_port);
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " .     $mysqli->connect_error . mysqli_error();
} else { echo 'OK';}
```

When i use the same script on my **Shared Host**, it will give me this error:
Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2003): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mydomain.com' (110) 

Any idea on how to solve this?
I also tried using the VPS ip instead of mydomain.com with the same results.
Also user admin has all privileges in MYSQL @ %

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some specific shared hosting, such as GoDaddy or HostPapa, you need to allow the IP address to be able to connect to the database. To do so, you can go the cPanel and go under **Remote MySQL**

Documentation:

1. [GoDaddy](https://ca.godaddy.com/help/connect-to-databases-remotely-16103)
2. [cPanel Forum](https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/enable-remote-access-to-customer-database.251951/)

Comment: Shared host and VPS are 2 different providers

Comment: Did you check the shared host for the remote myql setting?

Comment: Yes, they shared host wont let me to remotely access the shared host database for security reasons. They don't care if i use a database to another host (my vps)

Comment: @Google Just a question, when you say `mydomain.com` in your example, is it the mydomain host provider or your real domain?

Comment: my real domain that is hosted to my vps

Comment: Hey i checked again the host. Is my shared host issue. They wont let you use any other dbs. Thanks for the help

Comment: Oh I see! Which host you with?

Comment: Namecheap - any suggestion?

Comment: Oh never heard of it. I use GoDaddy, HostPapa, and MyDomain. If you want SSH access, don't go with HostPapa because they do not support it.